# Error: An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest not found Package:Newtonsoft.Json when deploying .Net core 2.2

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, json.net

I am deploying a .Net core 2.2 console application using self contained deployment and using some 3rd party libraries like(log4net and Newtonsoft.Json). The application is working fine on the system it is developed but not working when deployed to any other system. The below error displays:

`C:\Users\shubhamjain\source\repos\Collect\Collect\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\win-x64>Collect.exe`

> Error:
>     An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (Collect.deps.json) was not found:
>       package: 'Newtonsoft.Json', version: '12.0.2'
>       path: 'lib/netstandard1.3/Newtonsoft.Json.dll'

I have tried the below things:

1. Changing the .Net core version from 2.1 and 2.2
2. changing the version of Newtonsoft.Json from nuget
3. Updating visual studio 2019

Nothing worked but when I looked to a file ("Collect.runtimeconfig.dev.json" in path `C:\Users\shubhamjain\source\repos\Collect\Collect\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\win-x64`) and change the `shubhamjain` with the deployed system username, everything works fine.

> Now, What I observe that `Newtonsoft.Json` is depends on file (`.runtimeconfig.dev.json`) and in order to make it work I have to change the username in this file.
>
> Is there any way to resolve this automatically?

`Collect.runtimeconfig.dev.json` :

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
     "additionalProbingPaths": [
        "C:\\Users\\shubhamjain\\.dotnet\\store\\|arch|\\|tfm|",
        "C:\\Users\\shubhamjain\\.nuget\\packages",
        "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\\NuGetFallbackFolder" ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try configuring your `json` file with using `%username%` parameter. I am not sure if it is possible to run that way but you can use that parameter in the Command Prompt to get the logged in username. 
You can check the [link](https://www.windows-commandline.com/current-logged-in-user-name-command/) for more detail.

In this case your `Collect.runtimeconfig.dev.json` will be :

```
{
   "runtimeOptions": {
      "additionalProbingPaths": [
         "C:\\Users\\%username%\\.dotnet\\store\\|arch|\\|tfm|",
         "C:\\Users\\%username%\\.nuget\\packages",
         "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\\NuGetFallbackFolder" ]
   }
}
```

Also you can prepare different configuration files for different environments. Maybe [this Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2) could be helpful about that.

Comment: This does not work. Also, This is an .Net Core console application and I believe we do not have to pass any parameter for the username. There must be some another way.